# Loading external script with jQuery and no async

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to load an external script at a specific location on the page after two seconds and without async. In other words, the script needs to load exactly where I place it in the page HTML after two seconds. When I use the below code, I'm getting a console error:

> Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write
> into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless
> it is explicitly opened.

```
setTimeout(function(){
   $.ajax({
        url: 'https://example.com/embed.js',
        async: false,
        dataType: "script",
    });
}, 2000);
```

Why am I getting that error if I have async set to false?

Comment: Why can't you have that script loaded at start and simply execute it after 2s?

Comment: What do you mean by "the script needs to load exactly where I place it in the page HTML"? Also, your script `embed.js` is probably using `document.write`

Comment: `Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document'` ... *probably using `document.write`* ... great detective work there @Terry :P

Comment: I think what @Terry means is that you *really* don't want to be using document.write at all - use .append or .html or other friendlier methods to insert your html/text in the desired location.

Comment: ie, this is an XY Problem - your *real* issue is that you're trying to use document.write.  Note that document.write outputs *immediately* - there's no concept of "document.write after 2 seconds" - it's output in the stream as the stream is generated.  If it ran 2 seconds later, it would be after `</body></html>`.

Comment: I recommend you ask a new question along the lines of "how do I do this document.write after 2 seconds in this exact place" (and provide example doc.write and example html where you want it)

Comment: @freedomn-m `this is an XY problem` - my thoughts exactly. Seems like OP wants to execute a script after 2s (problem X), but they don't know how to do that, so they try to _load_ the script after 2s, but for some reason it must be executed immediately, so they want the whole thing to be synchronous (very bad idea) and it doesn't work (problem Y). So they ask a question about how to load a script synchronously (problem Y), instead of the original problem (X), which is to run a script after 2s.

Comment: @freedomn-m I think a better question would be 'How do I avoid using document.write in this script', but I agree with your point about this being an XY question

Comment: The script that is loading is for a third party form (Kajabi) and I can't change how they use document.write.

Comment: @JeremyThille That sounds like a possibility but I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yes, that's what I mean - I how do I achieve the equivalent of this doc.write.   Apologies it wasn't clear.

Comment: If it's a 3-party script, then maybe you could do this `<div class='showlater' style='display:none;'><script src="embed.js"></div>` then `$(() => { setTimeout(() => { $(".showlater").fadeIn(); }), 2000); })` (or equivalent if not 100% correct syntax in comment formatting)

Answer (score 0):

> Why am I getting that error if I have async set to false?

The `async` property only applies to XHR requests (and the functionality it triggers is deprecated there anyway). You said `dataType: "script",` so the request is handled by injecting a `<script>` element into the document and not by using XHR.

> I need to load an external script at a specific location on the page after two seconds and without async. In other words, the script needs to load exactly where I place it in the page HTML after two seconds.

Given the external script makes use of `document.write`, I don't think this is possible.

You should rewrite it to use DOM manipulation instead.

By making use of [`document.currentScript`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/currentScript) you can identify where in the DOM the `<script>` element was placed and insert the content there.

> The script that is loading is for a third party form (Kajabi) and I can't change how they use document.write

The nasty approach to this would be to let it write into an element that is set to `display: none` in CSS and then toggle the display value on a timer.